# Making an array from another defined array with no duplicates using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I had tried to make a list free of duplicates from another defined list using list comprehension as follows,

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
my_list = []
my_list = [x for x in num if x not in my_list]
```

Upon calling `my_list`, I get back the same array

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

Could anyone kindly explain why this is happening?

Comment: `my_list=list(set(num))`? If you don't care about the order.

Comment: `if x not in my_list` will *always* be true. Why would you expect otherwise if it's empty?

Comment: `[x for x in num if x not in my_list]` creates a new object which you are assigning to `my_list`. It doesn't add element in-place to `my_list` while iterating.

Comment: @Ch3steR Thank you for the clarification, much appreciated.

Comment: @yatu Thank you for the clarification, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`my_list` isn't updated until after the comprehension is complete. During the comprehension `my_list` is an empty list.

If order matters the approach you want to take is:

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
my_list = []
check_set = set()
for x in num:
    if x not in check_set:
        my_list.append(x)
        check_set.add(x)
```

If order does not matter:

```
my_list = list(set(num))
```

Comment: Props for being the only answer-poster to read the comments. But this is O(n^2). For large input sizes, using the set for "in" checks can pay off, even if it duplicates my_list's contents.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I've modified the answer to account for this inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Using set is more feasible than an if condition along with for loop:

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
my_list = list(set(num))
print(my_list)
```

Ouput:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

you should try something like this :

```
In [99]: num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
    ...: my_list = []

In [100]: [my_list.append(item) for item in num if item not in my_list]
Out[100]: [None, None, None, None, None]

In [101]: my_list
Out[101]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The list is updated after the list comprehension process is complete because which the duplicates are still present.

Comment: just pass it to set()

Comment: This is an obfuscated for loop. Comprehension is recommended over a loop for optimized object creation, but you discard it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this *list comprehension*.

```
my_list=[]
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
my_list=[my_list.append(x) or x for x in num if x not in my_list]
# [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you don't care about the order.

```
my_lst=list(set(num))
```

From Python3.6 and above dictionaries store the insertion order or use `collections.OrderedDict`. So, you can try this.

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
my_list=list(dict.fromkeys(num).keys())
```

You can use `seen` set to keep track of the elements that are seen. If an element in in `seen` don't add it to `my_list`.

```
num = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
seen=set()
my_list=[]
for x in num:
    if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        my_list.append(x)
my_list
# [1,2,3,4,5]
```